# Basis of eigenvectors of a self-adjoint operator with $\sigma(T) = \sigma_{p}(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $T$ is a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ with only point spectrum:
$$\sigma(T) = \sigma_{p}(T) = \{x \in H: (T-\lambda)x = 0\}$$
Eigenvectors associated to different eigenvalues are orthogonal. In the above case, is it true that one can find a basis of $H$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$?

Comment: My first answer was not correct., which was observed by John Doe. I have modified the answer, still trying to avoid spectral theorem. I think you could move acceptance from my answer to that of John Doe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A was observed by John Doe the claim is not true for nonseparable Hilbert space.

I assume  an orthonormal basis is considered in OP. The claim can be proved without applying the  spectral theorem.

Assume $\mathcal{H}$ is separable.
Let $\mathcal{H}_{\lambda} =\ker (T-\lambda I).$  Every subspace admits an orthonormal system $B_{\lambda}$ and $B_\lambda\cap B_\mu=\emptyset$ for $\lambda\neq \mu.$ We claim that $$B=\bigcup_{\lambda\in \sigma_p(T)}B_\lambda $$ is an orthonormal basis. Indeed,
the sum is countable as the set $\sigma(T)$ is countable.  Assume that $V=B^\perp.$ Due to the  self-adjointness, $V$ is a closed invariant subspace of $T.$ We have $\sigma(T\mid _V)\subset \sigma(T),$ hence  $\sigma(T\mid_V)$ is a countable compact subset of the real line. Therefore it contains isolated point $\lambda_0.$ Thus $\lambda_0$  is an eigenvalue of $T\mid_V,$ i.e. $\ker (\lambda_0 I-T)\cap V\neq 0,$ which leads to a contradiction.

**Remark** A proof that isolated point in the spectrum of a self-adjoint operator is an eigenvalue can be proved by continuous functional calculus. Namely let $f$ be a continuous real valued function such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\sigma(T),$ $x\neq x_0.$ Then $\sigma(f(T))=f(\sigma(T))=\{0,\ 1\}.$ We have $Tf(T)=x_0f(T),$ hence $x_0$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: A self-adjoint operator in infinite-dimensional Hilbert space can be non-zero without having eigenvectors.  For example on $L^2([0, 1])$ multiplication by $x$.

Comment: @JohnDoe OP assumes that $\sigma(T)=\sigma_p(T).$

Comment: Yes, but you claimed that the statement can be proved without the spectral theorem!  How do you conclude that your last $T$ is zero while relying on the assumption that $\sigma(T)=\sigma_p(T)$ without using the spectral theorem?  There is a leap in your argument.

Comment: @JohnDoe You are right. The spectra of $T$ restricted to $V$ and $V^\perp$ may overlap, so $T$ restricted to $V$ does not need to have eigenvectors.

Comment: The statment is still true in a separable Hilbert space because the point spectrum is countable - and the $\sigma$-additivity of the projection-valued measure allows to reach your conclusion that $T$ is zero on $B^{\perp}$.  It's a non-trivial use of the spectral theorem involved.

Comment: @JohnDoe In case of separable space the spectrum of $T$ on $B^\perp$ is countable and closed. So there are isolated points there, which are eigenvalues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145192/discussion-between-ryszard-szwarc-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because the spectral projection associated with a singleton of a point in the point spectrum is the projection on the eigenspace of that point, and the spectral projection of the entire spectrum is the identity operator.  It all follows from the spectral theorem if you study its exact detail.

In fact, it follows from the spectral theorem for that a self-adjoint operator that has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors - the closure of the point spectrum must be the whole spectrum.  The converse need not be true because a (self-adjoint) operator can have an independent continuous spectrum part that overlaps the closure of its point spectrum.

Edit: the difference between the first and second cases is that the point spectrum is countable, and the sigma-additivity of the spectral measure is used to establish the first statement if the point spectrum is the whole spectrum.  However, if you just know that that the closure of the point spectrum is the whole spectrum - it is insufficient to prove there's an eigenbasis because the whole spectrum may be uncountable!

Edit 2: I should mention that the discussion is for a separable Hilbert space.  In a non-separable Hilbert space the claim in the original post is *false*.  An operator can be constructed such that its point spectrum is the interval $[0,1]$, and it also has a continuous spectrum $[0, 1]$ so that there is no eigenbasis.